# Pasting to all sheets, except for the first 6

Tags: excel, vba

I don't really understand VBA, all I can do is paste a code I find that does what I need (thanks to all of your excellent answers to previous questions.) Sometimes I'm able to make simple modifications.

I found a code that's perfect for what I need to do (copy one worksheet to all other sheets), but I need to exclude the first 7 sheets.

The one I'm using already excludes the source sheet, but I haven't been able to figure out how to expand that to include more.

This is the code I'm using:

```vb
Dim aWshExcluded As Variant, vWshExc As Variant
aWshExcluded = Array("Exclude(1)", "Exclude(2)")
Dim WshSrc As Worksheet
Dim WshTrg As Worksheet

Rem Set Source Worksheet
Set WshSrc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2)
Application.ScreenUpdating = 0

    Rem Process All Worksheets
    For Each WshTrg In WshSrc.Parent.Worksheets

        Rem Exclude Worksheet Source
        If WshTrg.Name <> WshSrc.Name Then
              
            Rem Validate Worksheet vs Exclusion List
            For Each vWshExc In aWshExcluded
                If WshTrg.Name = vWshExc Then GoTo NEXT_WshTrg
            Next

            Rem Process Worksheet Target
            With WshTrg.Cells
                WshSrc.Cells.Copy
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll    'Everything is pasted.
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
                Application.Goto .Cells(1), 1
    End With: End If:

NEXT_WshTrg:
 
    Next

Application.Goto Worksheets("Main").Cells(1), 1
Application.ScreenUpdating = 1
End Sub
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

### Process Worksheets (With Exclusion)

- A safer way would be to write the names of the exclusion worksheets to an array and use `Application.Match` in the loop to find a worksheet name in the array.
- Using indexes instead of names is not recommended, e.g. if you move the 2nd worksheet to another position, the code will fail i.e. it will copy the wrong sheet. Also, if you move the main worksheet to a position greater than the `ExclusionCount` it will be overwritten.

**A Quick Fix**

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CopySheet()

    Const ExclusionsCount As Long = 7
     
    Dim Wbk As Workbook
    Dim WshSrc As Worksheet
    Dim WshTrg As Worksheet
    Dim n As Long
    
    Set Wbk = ThisWorkbook
    
    Set WshSrc = Wbk.Worksheets(2)
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False ' or 0
    
    For Each WshTrg In Wbk.Worksheets
        n = n + 1
        If n > ExclusionsCount Then
            WshSrc.Cells.Copy
            With WshTrg
                .Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
                Application.Goto .Cells(1), 1
            End With
        End If
    Next
    
    Application.Goto Worksheets("Main").Cells(1), 1
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True ' or "- 1" in VBA, not "1", although it works.

End Sub
```

### EDIT

**The Safer Way**

```vb
Sub CopySheetWithExclusions()

    Const ExclusionsList As String = "Main,Source," _
        & "Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday,Sunday"
     
    Dim Wbk As Workbook
    Dim WshSrc As Worksheet
    Dim WshTrg As Worksheet
    Dim Exclusions() As String
    Dim n As Long
    
    Set Wbk = ThisWorkbook
    Set WshSrc = Wbk.Worksheets("Source")
    Exclusions = Split(ExclusionsList, ",")
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    For Each WshTrg In Wbk.Worksheets
        If IsError(Application.Match(WshTrg.Name, Exclusions, 0)) Then
            WshSrc.Cells.Copy
            With WshTrg
                .Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
                Application.Goto .Cells(1), 1
            End With
        End If
    Next
    
    Application.Goto Worksheets("Main").Cells(1), 1
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks - I really appreciate it. You're right about using the sheet names, that's much better. They are "Main", "Source" and one for each of the work days, "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", Thursday", and "Friday", so actually 7, not 6. Would it be too much to ask how to create that? In any case - thanks for this!

Comment: This worked beautifully, of course. Thank you, very generous of you.